# Working Pull to refresh with disabled bounce

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, pull-to-refresh

I have UItableview and active UIRefreshControl for pull to refresh action. So I am trying to disable bounce (that appears when I scroll UITableView) by unselecting "bounce" property of tableview in storyboard. But when I do this pull to refresh also stops working. What can I do about this? Should I manually disable only bottom bounce and left top bounce for UIRefreshControl ?

My viewDidLoad method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Обновление")
    self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false;
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    // menu button
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code here? Because we don't need to set frame or start to `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`. Just adding `UIRefreshControl` will work like charm.

Comment: I added the code for viewDidLoad and also I have unchecked bounce property in storyboard

Comment: Why you want to disable the bounce of tableview? Is pull to refresh view appears behind that?

Comment: Bcs it is ugly and I also have slide menu that doesn't interact well with bouncing (slide menu is waiting until bouncing will end and only after that I can detect pan gesture and open menu). Pull to refresh doesn't appear when bouncing is off.

Comment: Is your refresh control added on table view?

Comment: Yes, it works fine if bounce is not disable

Comment: By definition, the pull to refresh uses the "bounce" to work.. cannot live without that.

Comment: I think you need to concentrate on the issues which happens when bounce is not disabled. Without bounce property refresh control can't identify its call..

Comment: I get it, thanks, u can add this answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. After implementing some code, I got a result that -unfortunately- the refresh control won't get called without letting the tableView bouncing.